# clash between mcode and scrbook

Tags: include, matlab, scrbook

I want to include Matlab code in my document. The [mcode](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) package used to do a great job in combination with my scrbook document class. However, I recently updated my KOMAscript family to version 3.12 and now the [mcode](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) package causes an error (incomplete \iffalse). The errror only occurs when I `\include` a `\chapter`; not when I prevent the use of `\include`. The MWE below reproduces the error; the error disappears when I change `scrbook` into `book`. Can anyone help me solve the problem?

```
\begin{filecontents}{testchap.tex}
\chapter{matlab code}
\mcode{function}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mcode}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\include{testchap}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but... consider using the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package instead of `mcode`; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The code is already a complete MWE, including the required packages and `\begin{document}`, and `end{document}`.

Comment: Why are you using a `filecontents` environment *before* loading the `filecontents` package?

Comment: Inspired - but possibly incorrectly - by another example on this forum ... it does work though ;-)

Comment: @Sander well the filecontents package isn't used at all, it's just loaded so "work" depends on your definition, also as you see in my MWE you don't actually need to include a file at all, simply having `\chapter` is enough.

Comment: `mcode` seems not to be on CTAN. So, a link to it would have been useful. I want to link instead to Werner’s answer with a link: [What can I use to typeset MATLAB code in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78393).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `komascript` classes and `mcode` define `\ifnumbered` in incompatible ways. This is surely the cause of the problem. One or the other (ideally both) should change the name of this switch, especially if it is needed only for internal purposes. I edited `mcode.sty`, changing instances of "numbered" (in `\ifnumbered` and `\numberedtrue`) to "mcode@numbered", and the MWE compiled fine.

`\ifnumbered` is used by `scrbook.cls` to discriminate between numbered and unnumbered chapters. It is used by `mcode` to discriminate between numbered and unnumbered code lines. In both cases it does seem to be an internal command and care should have been taken to choose a name not likely to cause such a conflict.

A workaround is to perform the described edits of `mcode.sty`. Here's the diff:

```
100,101c100,101
< \newif\ifnumbered
< \DeclareOption{numbered}{\numberedtrue}
---
> \newif\ifmcode@numbered
> \DeclareOption{numbered}{\mcode@numberedtrue}
118c118
< \ifnumbered\typeout{ - line numbering enabled}\else\fi
---
> \ifmcode@numbered\typeout{ - line numbering enabled}\else\fi
141c141
< \ifx\textquotesingle\undefined%
---
> \ifx\textquotesingle\undefined%
202c202
< \ifnumbered% numbered option
---
> \ifmcode@numbered% numbered option
212c212
<   \ifnumbered%
---
>   \ifmcode@numbered%
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, and thank you Florian Knorn for updating the [mcode](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) source according this suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

`scrbook` defines a macro `\ifnumbered` that isn't a TeX `if` which is not necessarily wrong but it is a bit dangerous and here `mcode` pushes you over a cliff.

You can restore `scrbook` s definition:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\let\zz\ifnumbered
\usepackage{mcode}
\let\ifnumbered\zz

\begin{document}

%\tracingall
\chapter{matlab code}





\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Well spotted. Of course, I'm biased against `mcode` but, in all objectivity, it's a shame it doesn't use `@` in its internals.

Comment: @Jubobs I'd say it was scrbook mostly to blame for this clash:-)

Comment: `mcode` uses an `\ifnumbered` switch, which is set to true if the `mcode` package option called `numbered` is used. Arguably, that switch should have been called `\mcode@ifnumbered` or something like that. I don't think `scrbook` should be blamed, here `:)` But I agree that starting a macro by "`\if`" when that macro is not a switch is bad practice.

Comment: @Jubobs there is a well entrenched convention going back to plain tex that macros called \ifzzzz are defined via \newif and have definition that is always \iftrue or \iffalse, had scrbook followed that convention it wouldn't matter if two packages define the same if.

Comment: I guess both `mcode` and `scrbook` should be blamed, but for different reasons.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It may not have mattered for this case, because `scrbook` only uses `\ifnumbered` locally. But `mcode` sets it globally and it *would* matter if another package (globally) defined the same if. So mcode really should have privatized their command.

Comment: @Dan well more important than who defined `\ifwhatever` is who gets the green tick and I see that's you in this case:-)